# A question based on Laplace transform ( Proving F(s+a) equal to this integral)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, laplace-transform

This question is from my assignments and I was unable to solve it and  I think I can't solve it without any help. I have been following Tom M Apostol.

> Assume f is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$ and let $F(z)= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt} f(t) dt$ , z=x+iy for x>c>0 . If s>c and a>0 prove that :

(a) F(s+a) = a$\int_{0}^{\infty} g(t) e^{-at} dt $ where $g(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t)dt$.

Attempt: LHS  is $F(s+a) =\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(s+a)t} f(t) dt$ and  RHS is a$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} \int_{0}^{t}e^{-sx} f(x) dx dt$ . I was thinking of using/ simplifying  RHS to obtain LHS but I am unable to do so  $e^{-at} \int_{0}^{t}e^{-sx} f(x) dx$. If there was $\infty$ instead of t then if would be F(s) but I am unable to understand what it would be in this case.

So, Can you please guide me in this question?

Comment: You need to spruce up your notations. They are a mess.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ut}|f(t)|dt<\infty$$
for real number $u>c>0$. Then
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} dt\,e^{-(\mathbf{Re}(s)+a)x}|f(t)|<\infty$$
for $\mathbf{Re}(s)>c$.

Now $f$ satisfies the premise of Fubini's theorem to be applied. We switch the order of integration of the following double integral.
\begin{align}
a\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} \int_{0}^{t}e^{-sx} f(x) dx dt&=\int_{0}^{\infty} dx\,e^{-sx}f(x)\int_x^\infty adt\,e^{-at} \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} dx\,e^{-sx}f(x)e^{-ax} \\
&=F(s+a).
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please tell how is using fubini's theorem allowed here?

Comment: @Avenger: The point is that the question should have stated the full property of $f$ but it has not. I am saying whichever $f$ that satisfies the premise of the Fubini's theorem would lead to the desired result. For example, the family of $f$ such that $\int_{0}^{t}|e^{-sx} f(x)| dx$ exists as a proper Lebesgue integral, or more specifically that $f$ is of the exponential type https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_type.  In any case, I have edited my answer to add more details and the needed supposition for the Fubini's theorem to be applied. Also, did you downvote my answer?

Comment: Will get back to you soon

Comment: @Avenger Currently very busy. Couldn't check it, but awarding you bounty.

Comment: @Avenger: OK. Let me know your question when you do have it. Are you going to accept and upvote my answer as well?